# ALB Cloudformation multiple conditions with AND in Listener rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I am trying to create a cloudformation template to create ALB with listener rules with below conditions:
[image]

However, I am getting invalid parameter error when template adds  these rules, I can add them in the UI but not via cloudformation.

Error:

```
Properties validation failed for resource ALBListenerRule2 with message: #/Conditions/1: extraneous key [sourceIpConfig] is not permitted
```

template:

```
`ALBListenerRule2:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupWebserver
          Type: forward
      Conditions:
        - Field: path-pattern
          PathPatternConfig:
            Values:
              - /user/signin
              - /user/signup
              - /flight
              - /user/gift2
        - Field: source-ip
          sourceIpConfig:
            Values:
              - !GetAtt My.PublicIp
      ListenerArn: !Ref ALBListener
      Priority: 1`
```

I couldn't find a document to add if/or/and conditions in the template.

I couldn't find a document to add if/or/and conditions in the template. template works when using the single condition in the template./

Comment: thanks for the solution, it fixed the error,  had a couple of other things incorrectly defined , fixed them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is because you have `sourceIpConfig`, instead of `SourceIpConfig`.